# error installing ADT in Eclipse: no repository found

Tags: android, eclipse, installation

I'm trying to install ADT in Eclipse, using the instructions on developer.android.com, but I'm getting an error...

**What I did:**
I installed the android SDK with the recommended exe-installer (the r15-version). I downloaded 2 platforms with it (Android 4.0 and 2.1).
Then I downloaded Eclipse Classic as recommended. I started Eclipse and added the plugin-repository. I get 4 packages from it, 3 of them I can install without problems, but the most important one (called "Android Development Tools" is throwing errors at me.

**The error**
When I try to install that one, It will run for a long time, and during that time my internet connection is VERY slow, almost not working anymore. After that I get the message that the installation failed, and in the details it says:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.xml,1.3.4.v201005080400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.highlighter,2.9.1.v20100421-0704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.memory,2.9.1.v20100421-0704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.misc,2.9.1.v20100421-0704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.queries,2.9.1.v20100421-0704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.snowball,2.9.1.v20100421-0704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.spellchecker,2.9.1.v20100421-0704
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xerces,2.9.0.v201101211617
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xml.resolver,1.2.0.v201005080400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xml.serializer,2.7.1.v201005080400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.7.0.v20110912-0920
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.7.0.v20110912-0920
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change,2.7.1.v20110829-1916
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi,2.7.0.v20110520-1406
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.7.1.v20110913-1526
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.util,2.1.100.v201103021400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.core,1.2.0.v200908252030
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emf,1.2.100.v201101101900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration,1.2.101.v201107140600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.environment,1.0.400.v200912181832
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks,1.2.101.v201107192200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.200.v201103170332
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.ui,1.1.500.v200911190730
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver,1.1.401.v201004280700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,1.1.601.v201108151912
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui,1.3.1.v201108191312
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation,1.2.302.v201107140600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.core,1.1.601.v201108302147
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui,1.1.201.v201108151912
```

I tried googling the problem but all I found were answers related to Linux-systems, and I'm running Win7 (Home Premium SP1 64bit if that makes any difference...)

I also tried using the repository-link with http instead of https, and also tried removing the repository and adding it back, but no luck with those actions either.

Can anybody help?

Comment: see the link for how to set up the android development tools step by step http://androidlearningbegin.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-first-program-helloworld-step.html in window 7.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I can download the ADT-zipfile from Google, so that should work a little better now. One question though: in step 7 it tells me to browse to the SDK-folder, but I cannot find out what input field should point to that folder. Could you help me out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you install the window installer downloaded in step-2 it would  be install in C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk

see the image [image]

then click on Apply

Comment: Thanks sunny! The SDK installed itself on my computer in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android". The weird thing is I don't have a antry in the preferences-screen called "Android", so the input-field for this is also not available. Am I missing something?

Comment: ok then first try to install ADT-plug-in step-9 and then go to window--->preference in eclipse and you will see the above image.

Comment: and then browse the android directory as shown in image and click apply

Comment: and better download the eclipse latest version.

Comment: Sunny, you're the absolute best! No idea what I did wrong the last time, but all of a sudden it started to work! I think the downloading of the SDK-zipfile did the trick, instead of getting it from the address provided in the tutorial from google itself.

Answer (score 4):

I was running into this same problem. I finally checked and was using the https: Google server instead of `http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
Switching the servers helped out. I found this in the troubleshooting section of [installing-adt](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).

Comment: For me it was the other way around. I was using http, switched to https and it worked.